# NoMethodError in FrontPages#home when I try to add a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am pretty sure it's a very noob mistake, but I don't understand why I can't add my form directly to my homepage without causing a NoMethodError.

This is my current setup, and it works perfectly fine.

view/front_pages/home.html.erb  (my home page)

```
<!--declare :title to be SHOULD I GET THIS-->
<% provide(:title, "SHOULD I GET THIS") %>
<div class = "container">
    <h1>Should I really spend money on this?</h1>
    <h2>Let's crunch in some numbers and find out...</h2>
    <%= link_to "Get Started", calculate_path, class: "btn btn-info " %>
</div>
```

view/users/new.html.erb (where my form is right now)

```
<% provide(:title, "Calculate")%>
<div class = "form-group container">
    <%= simple_form_for @user do |form|%>
        <%= form.error_notification%>
        <%= form.input :price%>
        <%= form.input :wallet%>
        <%= form.button :submit, "Submit", class: "submit"%>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

end
```

However, I want the form to be directly on my home page so the users don't need to click an extra button to get to the form. I tried

view/front_pages/home.html.erb

```
<!--declare :title to be SHOULD I GET THIS-->
<% provide(:title, "SHOULD I GET THIS") %>
<div class = "container">
    <h1>Should I really spend money on this?</h1>
    <h2>Let's crunch in some numbers and find out...</h2>
    <%= link_to "Get Started", calculate_path, class: "btn btn-info " %>
</div>
<div class = "form-group container">
    <%= simple_form_for @user do |form|%>
        <%= form.error_notification%>
        <%= form.input :price%>
        <%= form.input :wallet%>
        <%= form.button :submit, "Submit", class: "submit"%>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

and it returns me the NoMethodError. I thought it's because I did not initiate a @user variable in the front_page controller, so I tried

```
class FrontPagesController < ApplicationController
        def new
            @user = User.new
        end
    def home
    end
end
```

but it still does not work. I am thinking it's some concept about MVC that I still am not quite grasping. What is wrong with my code and what should I keep in mind next time so I don't make the same mistake?

PS: I use simple_form gem to generate my form

Edit: The error message is **undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class**

Comment: Post post the full error and the line that caused it.

Comment: sorry, i've added the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is quite simple:

> Undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

This error means you're trying to call the `model_name` method on a variable which is not populated with any data. *You* are not calling this method; `form_for` is - meaning you basically need to have `@user` declared in your controller, as you rightly pointed out:

```
class FrontPagesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end
    def home
    end
 end
```

--

**@user**

The problem is that you're using the `home` action - you're declaring your `@user` variable in the `new` action. This means it won't be set, as it won't be called.

You'll be best doing this:

```
class FrontPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
       @user = User.new
    end
 end
```

This will make `@user` available in your `home` action, which should resolve the error for you!

Comment: amazing, this works, thank you so much!! So is it safe to say that I cannot simply add a def new method in FontPageController because my file is named home.html.erb, therefore I need to declare all varialbes within def home?

Comment: No the controller actions are independent of each other - you can have as many actions as you want; but only declare variables you will need for each one

Answer (score -1):

You need specify the action for the form

```
<%= form_for :user, url: { action: create } do |f| %>
```

or you can use your path helper if you have a resource defined for user

```
<%= form_for :user, url: user_path do |f| %>
```